# How can I show rtf file with wmf images in ios

Tags: ios, image-processing, rtf, wmf

I have a `.rtf` file. It contains images with `Windows Metafile Format(wmf)`. I want to show this file in `iOS` app. I tried showing it using `NSAttributedString` and in `UIWebView` but images are not shown.
How can I show it on `iOS` device ?

**EDIT**

For `NSAttributedString`:

```
var urlpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("txtFile", ofType: "rtf")
var url:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlpath!)!
if let attributedText = NSAttributedString(fileURL: url, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil) {
    textView.attributedText = attributedText
}
```

For `UIWebView`:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"txtFile" ofType:@"rtf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

**EDIT2**

I tried converting `.rtf` file into `.rtfd` file format.

RTFD file creates a bundle with `TXT.rtf` and images in files. In `TXT.rtf` file, images are given as references  which are stored separately in RTFD. Like following :

```
{{\NeXTGraphic img1.png \width40 \height20}¬}
```

I converted the file into RTFD but issue comes when file contains `.wmf` images. Images with `.wmf` file format are not getting converted.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to `rtfd` insead of `rtf`

`Rich Text Format Directory`, also known as `RTFD` (due to its extension .rtfd), or Rich Text Format with Attachments

```
var urlpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("txtFile", ofType: "rtfd")
var url:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlpath!)!
if let attributedText = NSAttributedString(fileURL: url, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFDTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil) {
     textView.attributedText = attributedText
}
```